# Does AWS DMS has any way to touch or modify source tables?

Tags: mysql, aws-dms

I created several `Full load, ongoing replication task` DMS tasks to copy data from a VPS MySQL server to RDS MySQL, and after some tweaks (time zone config, collations, etc) I was able to get everything working as expected and replicating data effectively.

Yesterday however some tables were truncated in my source MySQL database (`TRUNCATE table_name`). The table statistics in the DMS task did detect a DDL change as appreciated in the below screenshot:

[image]

I was able to get the `TRUNCATE` commands from the MySQL binlog.

Questions:

- Is there any way that DMS could have been the culprit in literally truncating my source tables? My tasks don't even have the preparation mode `TRUNCATE`, I have `DO NOTHING`.
- I didn't find any way in the configs or in the docs but, does DMS have a way to affect source tables?

Edit:

I get the feeling that the VPS server got hacked. But I haven't been able to confirm if that's the case.

Edit 2:

Even some tables DMS didn't know about (were not included in the table mappings) got truncated as well.

Comment: did you look for new tables or databases created in your VPS server, with data telling you how to ransom your truncated tables?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find anything so far TBH. But the weird thing is that some tables DMS wasn't taking into account for the replication were truncated too.

Answer (score 0):

AWS DMS can not update/delete the source.
Please also refer to official documentation at:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html
regards,
Naveed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).